# Set of links with no agents

Tags: netlogo

I want to choose the set of links without a breed agents of talkers.

The code

breed [ talkers talker ]

ask patches with [ not any? talkers-here ]

With patches it works but no with links. I have been looking in the netlogo dictionary and testing some commands with no success. For instance, link-with will  returns a link not a set. `link-set' is my best chance but I can not make it works.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Get all the links that don't have any talkers at either end of the link:

```
links with [ not any? both-ends with [breed = talkers]]
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it works. I have to accomplish a model where agents move over links and I feel lost, even with questions that probably are not difficult. Like this one, even I do not know how to reference the actual link where an agent/talker is. I have run " ask link-with myself " and it does not work. Do you know what can be wrong? I would also appreciate if you can tell me a document tutorial or web page where I could understand how to work with links in Netlogo. Thank you.

Comment: A turtle cannot link to itself. You can test this by asking turtle 0 to create a link with itself.  For examples, go to the models library (file -> models library) and search link and there should be plenty of examples.